# Can cloud-config's write_files control whether a newline is appended to the file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-init, cloud-config

I'd like to use cloud-config in user-data on AWS to write a file, say /etc/myfile.  My experimentation so far seems to suggest that if the `write_files` block is the last bit of the user-data, then no trailing newline is written to the resulting file, whereas if there are other bits of config following then a newline is appended to the file.  For example:

```
#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: "/etc/myfile"
    permissions: "0444"
    owner: "root"
    content: |
      hello
  - path: "/etc/myfile2"
    permissions: "0444"
    owner: "root"
    content: |
      hello
```

...will generate two files.  But they will have different content:

```
[me@ip-172-31-40-207:~]$ cat /etc/myfile
hello
[me@ip-172-31-40-207:~]$ cat /etc/myfile2
hello[me@ip-172-31-40-207:~]$
```

Other than manually ensuring `write_files` is never at the bottom, is there any way to control whether newline is added, and is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that it was the pipe (`|`) that caused it, combined with the fact that I had omitted the trailing newline on the input.  So the solution is to omit the pipe, resulting in both files being written without a trailing newline.

The pipe means "maintain formatting of the following block of text", which cloud-init does correctly, including the newlines.  Because I had omitted the trailing whitespace (i.e. the very last newline in the above example) , `myfile2` was written without a trailing newline.